# OrientDB Embedded-List (of String): wildcard query

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I can't perform a wildcard-query on an embedded-list property of vertex (or edge).

For example:
Assume we have a `Person` class with a multi-value property named `Nicknames` and one instance of it:

```
   {
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#317:0",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "Person",
        "Nicknames": [
            "zito",
            "ziton",
            "zitoni"
        ]
   }
```

then,
`Select FROM Person WHERE Nicknames like "zit%"`
returns empty result-set, while:

`Select FROM Person WHERE Nicknames ="zito"` returns 1 item correctly.

There's a `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX` index on the field `Nicknames`.

I've tried many ways (contains, index-query...)  with no luck :(

I'm probably missing something basic.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: version 2.2.17 .

Answer (score 1):

I know is not an ideal solution what i'm going to write but, to stay stuck with your requirement of "query by wildcard" this is the only way that worked for me, as AVK stated is a better idea work with a Lucene index, but with the standard implementation i was unable to let it work, now here what i've done:

Use studio to create a javascript function with 2 parameter with name "array" and "rule", lets name the function "wildcardSearch"

past this code in the body of the function (is just simple javascript change it if it dosent do the job) :

```
 for(i=0; i<array.length ; i++){
       rule= rule.split("*").join(".*");
       rule= rule.split("*").join(".*");
       rule= "^" + ruleValue + "$";
       var regex = new RegExp(rule);
       if (regex.test(array[i]))
       return true;
   }
return false;
```

Remember to save the fucntion

now you can query:

```
Select from Person where wildcardSearch(nicknames,'zit*')=true
```

CONSIDERATIONS: is a brute force method, but show how "funny" can be play around with the "stored procedure" in OrientDb so i've decided to share it anyway, if performance are your main goal this things is not for you, it scan all the class and do the loop on the array to apply the regex. An Index is a way better solution, or change your db with a different data structure.

Comment: If no other option would be suggested (maybe by the project's contributors...), I'll use this direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select from Person where Nicknames containstext 'zit'
```

Hope that helps

Comment: ```containstext``` is good, but it doesn't let me use wildcards which is important feature for my needs (begins-with, ends-with...)

Comment: @Niro you could try using lucene indexing instead, but it's a little limited